# Login con Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

alguien sabe como puedo loggearme en esta [página](https://www.saes.escom.ipn.mx/) usando Jsoup?, he intentato esto:

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://www.saes.escom.ipn.mx/")

                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

Map<String, String> loginCookies = loginForm.cookies();

Document document = Jsoup
                    .connect("https://www.saes.escom.ipn.mx/").userAgent("Mozilla")
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .data("__EVENTTARGET", "")
                    .data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "")
                    .data("__VIEWSTATE", viewState)
                    .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventValidation)
                    .data("ctl00$leftColumn$LoginUser$UserName", usuario)
                    .data("ctl00$leftColumn$LoginUser$Password", password)
                    .data("ctl00$leftColumn$LoginUser$CaptchaCodeTextBox",captcha)
                    .data("LBD_VCID_c_default_ctl00_leftcolumn_loginuser_logincaptcha", id_captcha)
                    .data("LBD_BackWorkaround_c_default_ctl00_leftcolumn_loginuser_logincaptcha", "1")
                    .data("ctl00$leftColumn$LoginUser$LoginButton", "Iniciar")
                    .cookies(loginCookies)
                    .post();

Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.saes.escom.ipn.mx/alumnos/default.aspx")
                    .cookies(loginCookies)
                    .get();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
/Esto deberia mostrarme el HTMl de la pagina en la cual hice login
        System.out.println(doc);
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Isaias, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Comment: En el caso de esta pregunta es importante agregar que mensaje de error obtienes en caso de no conectarte. Por cierto, ¿Eres de la "ESCOM"?

Comment: No obtengo error, solo no me imprime el HTML de la pagina de inicio y no el de la pagina que le estoy indicando (https://www.saes.escom.ipn.mx/alumnos/default.aspx) , de hecho comprobe la consulta con Connection.Response y me regresa 200, osea que todo esta bien.
Si, soy de ESCOM

Comment: Isaias, algo importante es que el id_captcha puede ser diferente en cada sesión!, como puedes determinar el valor correcto al realizar la petición?

Comment: Lo sé, este id lo obtengo de la página con Jsoup, tambien obtengo la imagen del captcha en mi programa, ya tengo todos los datos pero al realizar la consulta y pedir que me devuelva el "Document" de la página a la que estoy accediendo con estos datos solo me regresa la misma página de inicio que es  https://www.saes.escom.ipn.mx , gracias por contestar :)

Comment: Para loguin te recomiendo utilizar [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).  Es mas sencillo para realizar loguin en paginas webs, ya que este te permite manipular los elementos html de manera directa, cosa que no es posible con Jsoup, ya que este esta creado para extraer datos del HTML.